# Why do Visual Studio 2010 DataTips look different between projects/solutions?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Sometimes the DataTips look like this....

[image: Pretty]

and sometimes like this...

[image: Ugly]

the code for each screenshot is (crude but) the same

```
    var list = new List<DateTime>();
    list.Add(DateTime.Now);
    list.Add(new DateTime());
```

Is a project setting or something else?

Comment: What's the difference? One shows properties. The other shows methods and fields.

Comment: @Cody: I have updated the example to demonstrate the difference more clearly

Comment: So, the question is, what did you change to get the two screenshots? Like Hans, I expected the second one to be from a C++/CLI project. I've never seen the `^` notation show up in the IntelliSense for a C# project.

Comment: Is it possible that you've compiled the first in in Debug mode (optimizations disabled) and the second in Release mode (optimizations enabled)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using two different IDEs.  The first screenshot is what you'll typically get from the debugger in a VB.NET or C# project.  The second is a C++/CLI project compiled to 64-bit code.  The 64-bit debugger is special, you are actually using the remote debugger.  Required because Visual Studio is a 32-bit process.  Debugger visualizers make a difference as well.  And there's something really wrong with that *list* variable.

Comment: both screen shots are taken from c# class library projects. I am running on a 64-bit machine though. The list variable in the screenshot was just thown in to grab a screenshot of. It is just a list of datetimes with 2 entries.... yet it displays like that when debugging!

Comment: Well, the debugger is clearly suffering from a heart attack in the 2nd screenshot.  Nothing much sane it can do when it cannot get the type info, falling back to insane mode is not unexpected.  The ^ characters you see is C++/CLI notation.  Before calling this a debugger bug (install SP1 btw), assume that something really nasty happened in your program.  Like corruption of the GC heap.

Comment: Btw, debugging in x86 mode is much friendlier, Edit + Continue is enabled too.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target = x86.  It is the default setting in VS2010.

Comment: There is nothing set in the project/solution telling it to target x64. It is set to Any CPU. The test project I created (that output the top screenshot) was also set to Any CPU. SP1 is installed

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've set the "Hexadecimal Display" option.

When you hit a breakpoint right click over the "Locals" or "Watch" window and clear the checkbox from the context menu.

I thought that was global, but it might well be on a per project basis.